# Isogenic elliptic curves. Number of points and zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Is there any book or other reference where I can find a complete proof of the following fact?

If $E$ and $E'$ are two isogenic curves (over $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q=p^a$), then for any $n \ge 1$ the number of points over $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ is the same for both $E$ and $E'$ and they also have the same zeta function over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof can be found in
Waterhouse, William C. Abelian varieties over finite fields. Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup. (4) 2 1969 521--560. It is proved there more generally for abelian varieties (elliptic curves are $1$-dimensional abelian varieties):

If $A, A'$ are two $g$-dimensional abelian varieties over $\mathbb{F}_q$, then the following are equivalent:

(i) They are $F_q$-rationally isogenous.
(ii) They have the same characteristic polynomial of Frobenius.
(iii) For all $1 \leq i \leq g, \ |A(F_{q^i})| = |A'(F_{q^i})|$.
(iv) The Hasse-Weil zeta functions of A and A' coincide.

I suppose that a proof can also be found in Silverman's book *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* (see $16.5.2$ on page $363$ for the statement - two elliptic curves are isogeneous over $\mathbb{F}_q$ if and only if they have the same number of points; which just says that the zeta functions coincide ).